# Script function not found : doGet

Tags: python, django, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

These are the sample code i am running
"script_url" is the google script web app deployed and the url generated

sample.py

```py
import requests
import datetime

url = "script_url?client_name={}&client_address={}&company_name={}&company_address={}&vessel_name={}&po={}&id={}&date={}&item1={}&item2={}&item3={}&cost1={}&cost2={}&cost3={}&total={}"

name_client = ["inder", "sawpnesh", "kajal"]
address_client = ["addInder", "addswapnesh", "addkajal"]
name_company = ["ospl", "ospl", "ospl"]
address_company = ["addospl", "addospl", "addospl"]
vessel_name = ["redlips", "elizabth", "jack"]
po = ["EWDCC", "wefwec", "asxwq"]
invoice_ids = ["1", "2", "3"]
item1 = ["keyboard", "mouse", "screen"]
item2 = ["mouse", "screen", "keyboard"]
item3 = ["screen", "keyboard", "mouse"]
cost1 = ["1000", "500", "2000"]
cost2 = ["500", "2000", "1000"]
cost3 = ["2000", "1000", "500"]

i = 0
for invoice_id in invoice_ids:
    total = cost3[i] + cost2[i] + cost1[i]
    print("processing ", invoice_id)
    response = requests.get(
        url.format(name_client[i], address_client[i], name_company[i], address_company[i], vessel_name[i], po[i],
                   invoice_id, datetime.date.today(), item1[i], item2[i], item3[i], cost1[i],
                   cost2[i], cost3[i], total
                   ))
    # response = requests.get(
    #     url.format(invoice_id, cust_names[i], add_streets[i], add_citys[i], issue_dates[i], last_dates[i]))
    print("file generated")
    response = requests.get(response.content)
    print("file downloaded")
    i += 1
    with open("invoice{}.pdf".format(invoice_id), "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    # i += 1
```

This is the google script app I am running
code.cs

```js
function createDocument(id,client_name,client_address,company_name,company_address,vessel_name,po,date,item1,item2,item3,cost1,cost2,cost3,total) {
  var TEMPLATE_ID = 'template_id';  
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy().getId();
  
  drivedoc = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  drivedoc.setName("Invoice " + id+"/2021");
  
  doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText('{id}', id);
  body.replaceText('{client_name}',client_name);
  body.replaceText('{client_address}',client_address);
  body.replaceText('{company_name}',company_name);
  body.replaceText('{company_address}',company_address);
  body.replaceText('{vessel_name}',vessel_name);
  body.replaceText('{po}',po);
  body.replaceText('{date}',date);
  body.replaceText('{item1}',item1);
  body.replaceText('{item2}',item2);
  body.replaceText('{item3}',item3);
  body.replaceText('{cost1}',cost1);
  body.replaceText('{cost2}',cost2);
  body.replaceText('{cost3}',cost3);
  body.replaceText('{total}',total);
  
  drivedoc.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);

  return "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + documentId + "/export?format=pdf";
}
function doGet(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var client_name = e.parameter.client_name;
  var client_address = e.parameter.client_address;
  var company_address = e.parameter.company_address;
  var company_name = e.parameter.company_name;
  var vessel_name = e.parameter.vessel_name;
  var po = e.parameter.po;
  var date = e.parameter.date;
  var item1 = e.parameter.item1;
  var item2 = e.parameter.item2;
  var item3 = e.parameter.item3;
  var cost1 = e.parameter.cost1;
  var cost2 = e.parameter.cost2;
  var cost3 = e.parameter.cost3;
  var total = e.parameter.total;

  var url = createDocument(id,client_name,client_address,company_name,company_address,vessel_name,po,date,item1,item2,item3,cost1,cost2,cost3,total);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(url);
}
```

When I execute the url
`script_url?client_name=inder&client_address=addinder&company_name=ospl&company_address=ospladd&vessel_name=SEAQUEEN&po=324231&id=1&date=12/1/21&item1=keyboard&item2=mouse&item3=&cost1=1000&cost2=500&cost3=&total=1500`

it gives me the following error.

[image]

I am not able to use this script to input the data to my google doc template with template id `TEMPLATE_ID` using google script. My python code is running fine.   Please help me on how to fix this issue

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail settings of your Web Apps, for example, when you redeploy your Web Apps as new version, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize. By the way, can I ask you about the relationship between your error message and your python script?

Comment: @Tanaike, so i have tried redeploying and altogether making a new script and deploying it again. but it keeps showing this error, and if i dont pass all the values lets say if i dont write cost3 and total in the linnk it will give me a different error which is -"Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. (line 8, file "Code")".------

Comment: and as for the relation between the error and my python is that m basically trying to get a invoice whos.so i am taking input on my django app from html file and then trying to render those inputs to my template using the google scripts.my python script is running fine but the google script is not rendering the details to the template.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I confirmed that the error message was changed from `Script function not found : doGet` to `Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. (line 8, file "Code")`. From this new error message, it is found that the script of Web Apps is run. By this, it is found that my proposal was resolved your issue.

Comment: But at your new issue, it seems that your Google Document cannot be accessed. So can you confirm your situation again? By the way, can you provide the detail settings of your Web Apps? I'm not sure about the detail settings of your Web Apps. I apologize for this.

Comment: no no no its other way around.  Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. (line 8, file "Code") is the first error.which i solved but then i m getting the Script function not found : doGet error.   and can u please elaborate what details you want? google script or python?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `no no no its other way around. Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. (line 8, file "Code") is the first error.which i solved but then i m getting the Script function not found : doGet error`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230383/discussion-between-inderjeet-singh-yadav-and-tanaike).

Comment: Have you ever managed to get a very basic web app running? With a simple doGet? Or is it something about the more complex setup that you have?

Comment: @iansedano yea i have a small scrip with 4-5 variables.that gave me the output no problem.but the difference was that the google script was accessed by a single python file, not django python file if that makes any difference. and yea i m trying a not exactly complex its just the nearly same code with a lot more variables.

Comment: Are you sure that you have redeployed the web app after making changes?

Comment: i made an entirely different web app altogether.

Comment: This is very confusing...there should be no difference from python or django, as long as the request is ok. Are you sure the spreadsheet IDs are the correct ones and that you have access? So far what you have posted is not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. So i fixed this issue by creating a completely different script